# Error Uncaught SyntaxError: missing al agregar un evento OnClick desde js a un elemento

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, onclick

Tengo en Js un array al que quiero agregarle un botón que tenga un evento onclick

estoy creando ese botón desde un elemento en js

```
load("files", function (response) {
    multipleFileUploadError.style.display = "none";
    var content = "<p>Archivos Cargados: </p>";

    response.forEach((file, index) => rollCall(file, index));

    
    for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
        content += "<p>Descargar Archivo : <a href='" + response[i] + "' target='_blank'>" + response[i] + "</a></p>" + "<input type='button' value='Eliminar'  onClick='eliminar(" + response[i] + ");'>";

    }
    multipleFileUploadSuccess.innerHTML = content;
    multipleFileUploadSuccess.style.display = "block";
});
```

Lo que quiero es obtener el valor que tiene  `response[i]` y mandarlo a otro método

```
function eliminar(url) {
    console.log('1 ' + url);
}
```

Pero me manda el error de `(index):1 Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list (at (index):1:10)`

Entiendo que estoy mandando mal el valor, me podrian ayudar con la forma correcta por favor

Comment: probé tu función, y parece estar funcionando bien, tanto la de files, como la de eliminar, tu error probablemente venga de otro lado, por ejemplo, ¿qué viene en response?

Answer (score 0):

No se si será el problema al añadir el codigo html en content, el problema creo que es en la función onClick que le quieres añadir a cada botón que creas.

Podrías no añadir la función onClick, y luego añadir un eventlistener a cada botón para que ejecute la función eliminar.

```
load("files", function (response) {
multipleFileUploadError.style.display = "none";
var content = "<p>Archivos Cargados: </p>";

response.forEach((file, index) => rollCall(file, index));


for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
    content += "<p>Descargar Archivo : <a href='" + response[i] + "' target='_blank'>" + response[i] + "</a></p>" + "<input type='button' className="btn-eliminar" value='Eliminar' >";
    // no se si en el html se usa para la clase class o className

}
multipleFileUploadSuccess.innerHTML = content;
multipleFileUploadSuccess.style.display = "block";

const buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("btn-eliminar");
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].addEventListener("click", ()=>eliminar(response[i]);
}
});
```

Comment: Estimado no veo como su código soluciona el problema, es más lo hace más complejo. Además que el error es claro, solo hay un problema de sintaxis

Comment: @yussef me podrias decir en que parte de la sintaxis me equivoque, soy nuevo en js

Comment: @Ivannava Lo más probable es que tu error no esté en el código que publicaste, por lo menos no se ve que algo estuviera mal y tal como te señaló JorgeAlmada, es probable que el error esté en otra pieza de código. Si tu ejecutas tu programa, y presionas F12 para ver la consola y ves que aparece un error este pone un link en (index):1:10, si presionas ese link te lleva a donde está el error